# Best way to store 3rd party DLLs in VS 2008 +

Tags: visual-studio

What is the standard practice to store DLLs in a solution ,where the dlls are used in  multiple projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a Library folder, put any third party dll's in there, and then reference the library dll's in projects.

Answer (score -1):

Create a common store or folder for where the DLL's will be located, for example `bin` and put those shared DLL's into that folder, and ensure the applications that are using those shared DLL's, to look into the `bin` folder

```
MyAppFolder <-- Applications
   |
   +---- bin    <-- Shared DLLs
```

Comment: @Adam: I was talking about the finished deployed project...not in reference to Visual Studio's own bin folder...

Comment: @Adam could you explain why that's bad?

Comment: @tommieb75: In that case, why even put them in a folder rather than in the root directory? And I don't believe that pertains to the question, as he's asking where to store them in the project hierarchy.

Comment: @lincolnk: Because the `bin` folder is managed by Visual Studio. You run the risk of files being added/removed/modified out from under you, and introducing source control (which generally locks files that aren't checked out) would break the build process unless you left the files in question perpetually checked out. The project folder hierarchy is for storing project files, the `bin` folder is for compiler-generated output.

Comment: @Adam if you're adding a prebuilt dll to the bin and using that as the reference point, what is going to change it and if it doesn't change why would it interfere with the build process? 

i'll admit to going this route in a couple projects where i had some dll to drop into the project, and everything seemed to work smoothly. visual studio knew what was going on and dealt with it appropriately. tfs may have been checking things out/in while i wasn't looking but i don't think that's the case.